# Перебор элементов контейнера - очень медленная операция

Tags: c++, оптимизация, vector, контейнеры

столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

есть контейнер данных

```
std::vector<CStatistics> m_statistics;
```

с этими данными приходится много работать, часто вызывая такой функционал

```
for (auto &statistics : m_statistics)
    statistics.analyze(inputData);
```

с этим ничего не поделать, такова жизни :)

общая обработка данных занимает очень много времени (до нескольких суток в 10 потоках, но и данных терабайты)

решил узнать в чём проблема и постараться соптимизировать

оказалось, что сам анализ занимает лишь 50% времени, а 50% занимает просто перебор элементов контейнера (специально функцию analyze сделал в виде

```
{
    return;

    // основной функционал
}
```

для проверки

перебрал вроде все контейнеры и даже обычный динамический массив - все даёт такое же время работы

единственное ускорение (на 18%) дало предварительное выделение памяти под элементы контейнера:

```
m_statistics.reserve(20000);
```

**Подскажите**, можно ли как-то это дело ускорить, сделать оптимальнее? Общие соображения (потому что кол-во данных, сам анализ и т.д. останутся теми же, да и их оптимизация - это уже другая задача)

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

**Основная задача:**

есть научные данные (~1ТБ и выше), представляющие собой последовательность блоков данных (всего 10 миллиардов и выше)

данные считываются примерно по 1ГБ (50 миллионов блоков) в память и с ними последовательно (блок за блоком) работаю задачи

есть задачи анализа этих данных

задачи реализованы в виде классов, отнаследованных от базового интерфейса (просто показывает в каком виде данные получать и в каком сохранять)

задачи разбиты на большие группы, группы анализируются в отдельных потоках ибо никак друг с другом не связаны

в конкретном случае одна группа содержит 1500 одинаковых задач, но с разными входными параметрами

эти задачи (как объекты) объединены в вектор

каждый блок данных из считанной совокупности блоков передаётся каждой задаче

именно это и выполняется цикл

```
for (auto &statistics : m_statistics)
    statistics.analyze(inputData);
```

и именно это отнимает 50% времени :)

конечно я мог бы заморочиться и сделать жуткую оптимизацию, но тогда потерялась бы необходимая для расширения задач универсальность, что ни в коем случае нельзя делать - на разработку времени больше потрачу, чем на анализ :)

поэтому каждая задача работает независимо, внутри анализ оптимизирован конечно

**P.S.**

возможно это связано с тем, что задачи могут быть шаблонно-отнаследованными, но компилятор, мне казалось должен нормально все эти вызовы из вызовов оптимизировать, т.е.

```
class CInterface;

template <class CElement>
class CBase: public CInterface;

class CTask1 : public CInterface;

class CTasksGroup: public CBase<CTask1>;
```

и естественно вызов

```
group.task.analyze();
```

---

Поскольку просили более полный код

код считывания пакетов данных (удалил ненужное)
для удобства сделал непрерывное считывание как из контейнера
на самом деле считывается буфер из файла, потом данные передаются из буфера, когда надо буфер опять обновляется (по 1ГБ где-то, содержит миллионы пакетов данных)

```
// проанализировать файл
template <class IExtractorData>
void
CTasksManager::ProcessPacketsFile
()
{
    // инициализировать экстрактор
    CExtractor<IExtractorData> extractor(m_dataPath, m_infoManager);

    // обработать данные
    for (CExtractor<IExtractorData>::iterator it = extractor.begin(); it != extractor.end(); ++it)
    {
        // распарсить данные о пакете данных
        CPacketData packetData = *it;

        // собрать статистику
        for (auto &filteredStatisticsIt : m_statisticsData)
        {
            filteredStatisticsIt.analyze(packetData);
        }
    }

    // деактивировать экстрактор
    extractor.close();
}
```

код анализа пакета данных

```
// проанализировать сетевой пакет
bool
CStatisticsFilteredData::analyze
(
    CPacketData& packetData             // пакет данных
)
{
    // отпределить, должен ли пакет данных участвовать в сборе статистики
    if (m_filteredFunc(packetData) == false)
        return false;

    // вспомогательный анализ пакета данных

    // выполнить задачи анализа данных
    for (auto taskIt : m_tasks)
    {
        taskIt.second->add(packetData);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Код задачи (выкинул всё ненужное, оставил только то, что тестирую)

```
template<class ICustomStatistics>
class СStatistics_R2 : public IBaseStatistics
{
protected:
    using statistics_block_t = std::pair<double, ICustomStatistics>;
    using statistics_set_t = std::vector<statistics_block_t>;

protected:

    statistics_set_t                     m_statistics;

public:
                    СStatistics_R2();

    void            add(const CBasePacketData& packetData) override;
};

template<class ICustomStatistics>
СStatistics_R2<ICustomStatistics>::СStatistics_R2
()
{
    m_statistics.reserve(5000);

    // подготовка вектора m_statistics, который содержит подзадачи ICustomStatistics (которые являются независимыми задачами и так же наследуются от IBaseStatistics)
    for (int index = 0; index < 1500; index++)
        m_statistics.push_back(statistics_block_t(index, ICustomStatistics(...)));
}

// проанализировать пакет данных
template<class ICustomStatistics>
void
СStatistics_R2<ICustomStatistics>::add
(
    const CBasePacketData& packetData
)
{
    for (auto &statistics : m_statistics)
        statistics.second.add(packetData);
}
```

базовый класс `IBaseStatistics`:

```
class IBaseStatistics
{
public:
    virtual void            add(const CBasePacketData& packetData) = 0;         // проанализировать пакет данных
};
```

`ICustomStatistics` из класса `СStatistics_R2` выглядит так (их несколько, но в одной группе задач используется один класс, только с разными входными параметрами)

```
class CStatistics_Intensity : public CStatistics_BaseIntensity
{
protected:
    _i64    get_packet_value(const CBasePacketData& packetData) const;

public:
    CStatistics_Intensity (...);
};

CStatistics_Intensity::CStatistics_Intensity
(
...
)
    : CStatistics_BaseIntensity(...)
{}

_i64
CStatistics_Intensity::get_packet_value
(
    const CBasePacketData& packetData       // пакет данных
) const
{
    return (_i64)packetData.packetSize;
}
```

который унаследован от класса `CStatistics_BaseIntensity`

```
class CStatistics_BaseIntensity : public CBaseStatistics
{
protected:
    virtual _i64    get_packet_value(const CBasePacketData& packetData) const = 0;

public:
    CStatistics_BaseIntensity();

    void        add(const CBasePacketData& packetData) override;
};

CStatistics_BaseIntensity::CStatistics_BaseIntensity
(
...
)
    : CBaseStatistics(...)
{
}

void
CStatistics_BaseIntensity::add
(
    const CBasePacketData& packetData       // пакет данных
)
{
    return 0; // ВОТ ТУТ ПОСТАВИЛ ЗАГЛУШКУ И ИЗМЕРЯЛ СКОРОСТЬ
    get_packet_value(packetData);
}
```

ну и класс `CBaseStatistics` просто наследуется от интерфейса `IBaseStatistics`

```
class CBaseStatistics: public IBaseStatistics
```

и определяет необходимый функционал

такое многократное наследование, потому что разные задачи являются подзадачами других задач и содержат по сути большую часть функционала

**P.S.**

ну и сами задачи задаются просто (например)

```
for (const auto binWidth : binWidthsList)
    addTask("[0061]_analyze_r2[bw=" + to_precision_string(binWidth, 0) + "bps]",
        new СStatistics_R2<CStatistics_Intensity>(0.001, 10000.000, binWidth));
```

**P.P.S.**

```
    // выполнить задачи анализа данных
    for (auto taskIt : m_tasks)
    {
        taskIt.second->add(packetData);
    }
```

некоторые пояснения по поводу этого кода:

во первых спасибо за подсказку - действительно забыл поставить ссылку `auto&`, сейчас добавил

во вторых m_task - это

```
using tasks_pr = std::pair<std::string, IBaseStatistics*>;
using tasks_t = std::map<std::string, IBaseStatistics*>;

tasks_t             m_tasks;                        // список задач анализа данных для класса пакетов данных
```

т.е. классов не так и много и сам объект `tasks_pr` не так много места занимает, чтобы его копирование было критичным по времени

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95879/discussion-on-question-by-zhihar-c-----).

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко "Горячая" обозначает наиболее часто выполняющаяся операция с точки зрения профилирования, и накладные расходы тут не имеют никакого значения. Их оптимизация не уменьшит частоту выполнения. Т.е. будет там одна команда между переходами или больше она все равно останется константой слабо влияющей на общую сложность.

Comment: Хм.. Ты самого главного не сказал - какой компилятор?

Comment: я бы попробовал хранить  контейнер в классе, и перебор его элементов выполнять в методе класса, который легко встраивается

Comment: Как много операций выполняет (analyze)? Накладные расходы на цикл, вызов функции, работе с таблицей виртуальных функций и т.д. от силы несколько десятков асемблеровских команд в сумме. Если в analyze выполняется что-то сложное, то проблема явно не в накладных расходах на эти операции. Да и при чтении вы, наверняка, делали аналогичный цикл для заполнения массива. И работал он быстро.

Comment: А вообше то, основываясь на прошлом вашем вопросе,  например,  в классе СStatistics_Periodic  вы определяете    вектор  итераторов.  Не знаю для чего это, но  внушает подозревать, что архитектура неудачная

Comment: Реально недостает данных. Нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy - *Ты самого главного не сказал - какой компилятор?* - тот, что встроен в Visual Studio 2017

Comment: если это msvc17, то у нее есть встроенный профайлер, запустите ваш код и посмотрите.

Comment: @Zhihar По вашему получается перебор вектора по нагрузке сопоставим с обработкой 1 ГБ данных! Никогда не поверю, это просто невозможно! Вы явно где-то ошибаетесь. Годать не нужно, используйте профилировщик, сразу будет видно где задержки.

Comment: Поскольку просили более полный код код считывания пакетов данных ...

Comment: @MrBin, *Реально недостает данных* - добавил кусок реального кода

Comment: @goldstar_labs, с профилеровщиком какая-то проблема выходит - не хочет глубоко заходить (может из-за шаблонов?) но еще повожусь

Comment: @Cerbo, да! и именно это меня и смутило!!! если быть точнее - сопоставим вообще с анализом данных (что 1 ГБ, что 1 ТБ не важно - там все линейно)

Comment: `for (auto taskIt : m_tasks)` Вы уверены что не `for (auto& taskIt: m_tasks)` или `for (const auto& taskIt: m_tasks)`? Почему по значению?

Comment: @vegorov, действительно, внес исправление, спасибо, но на скорость это не сказалось, потому что там была работа с указателями (т.е. копирования небольшого объёма данных)

Comment: то есть `taskIt` - это указатель? Почему тогда там используется оператор точка  `taskIt.second`?? Или всё таки это объект пользовательского типа, к примеру, `std::pair<...>`? Для пользовательских типов лучше всегда итерироваться по ссылке или констатной ссылке

Comment: CStatisticsFilteredData::analyze принимает ссыльку на   CPacketData. Зачем вы создаете новй экземпляр в каждой итерации  метода  CTasksManager::ProcessPacketsFile, чтобы передать в эту функцию. сразу передайте ссыльку *it... И других проблем тоже у вас немало...

Comment: Это не минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Всем будет легче, если вы предоставите ссылку на godbolt или pasterbin с минимальным кодом и примером, где у вас итерирование занимает 50% от всего времени.

Comment: Только не с полным кодом, а с минимальным кодом, позволяющим воспроизвести такое поведение.

Comment: @vegorov, добавил в описание как выглядит `m_tasks` - это `std::pair<std::string, IBaseStatistics*>`, поэтому в коде и есть `.second->`

Comment: А давно копирование пары, где есть целый `std::string`, стало дешёвой операцией?

Comment: @vegorov, согласен, но по сравнению с остальным вклад был очень незначительный, поэтому и незамеченный :) после правки (выставления ссылки) одной проблемой стало меньше

Comment: Извините, но на мой взгляд, это не примеры кода, а набор каких-то абстракций, не поддающихся реальному анализу. По крайней мере я так и не смог понять, каково количество итераций в приведенных циклах и каковы размеры (в байтах) элементов, которыми вы оперируете.

Comment: А также, какая ОС (я уже спрашивал)? Данные на HDD в файле или это raw device? Т.е. откуда и как вы берете данные мне тоже не ясно.

Comment: @avp, ОС - Windows, данные c HDD (считывание занимает время, но тестирую я после однократного считывания 1ГБ в память), кол-во итераций?  50.000.000 итераций в цикле по получению пакетов данных (т.е. будет однократно получено 50.000.000 пакетов данных), далее для каждого пакета данных вызывается 1500 задач (предварительно создано со своими параметрами 1500 классов, отнаследованных как я показал выше, имеющих одинаковы метод `add'), для каждого пакета данных для каждой из 1500 задач вызывается функция `add`, выполнение которой я сразу прекращаю по `return` (для теста)

Comment: @avp, каждому из 1500 объектов поставлен в соответствие некоторый коэффициент, вместе они образуют пару `std::pair<double, *IBase>`, где `*IBase` указатель на объект класса, все 1500 пар хранятся в векторе, который я для каждого пакета данных и пробегаю

Comment: Я правильно понял, что обрабатывая 50.000.000 пакетов с помощью 1500 задачи, то получается 750.000.000.000 итераций по циклу `for`? Даже если процессор будет выполнять весь цикл за 1 наносекунду, то на весь цикл уйдет 750с или 12,5 минут. Что невозможно на обычных компьютерах.

Comment: MrBin ну примерно так и получается - 10 миллиардов пакетов обрабатывается около 50-60 часов, т.е. один буфер (50 миллионов) обрабатывается 15-20 минут из которых. Конечно каждый пакет обрабатывается по разному - например 100 пакетов могут пропуститься, а следующий анализироваться и т.д.,но для всех 10 миллиардов будет вызвала функция `add`, в которой и пройдет проверки. Частично время тратится (как я теперь понял) из-за наследования и виртуальных функций. Сделал частный случай класса с полным функционалом - скорость возросла (~20%), но я думал, что компиляторы такие вещи оптимизируют все же

Comment: Добавлю копию рекомендации в основную ветвь комментариев.  -- Видимо надо **отсортировать данные** (разбросать их по **разным векторам** на этапе чтения файла) таким образом, чтобы в группу задач попадали **только нужные данные**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for (auto &statistics : m_statistics)
> ```

Насколько я понимаю, в векторе хранятся данные разных типов, а значит сам вектор содержит указатели, а не объекты. В таком случае добавление лишнего уровня указателя только замедляет перебор, поскольку требуется лишнее разыменование.

Далее, как ни странно, компиляторы не полностью оптимизируют работу с итераторами в for each и простой цикл по индексу до размера может оказаться несколько быстрее, чем цикл с итератором. Особенно сильно это было заметно в VS2010, но сейчас ideone тоже показал небольшую разницу.

На примере [с суммированием](https://ideone.com/KN8W1k) разница находится в пределах погрешности.

```
3852871726
Index: 41888244
1275459847
Byval: 42361756
2080980504
Byref: 43436973
```

Но на более сложных примерах (см ниже) разница всё же видна.

А ещё программу может замедлять вызов виртуальных функций:

- [Виртуальные функции](https://ideone.com/RCtNma): 2.85 сек.
- [switch по типу](https://ideone.com/tPlm81): 2.45 сек. - быстрее на 14%
- [switch по типу и цикл по индексу](https://ideone.com/4mnkSP): 2.22 сек. - ещё на 10%
- [switch по типу и цикл по индексу до переменной](https://ideone.com/3sIXHl): 2.27 сек. - в пределах погрешности

---

#### Код с ideone:

Пример с суммированием чисел в векторе https://ideone.com/KN8W1k

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

#define MAXN 100000000

class timer
{
  using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
  T t1, t2;
public:
  void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void stop() { t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void print(const char *title) const { std::cout << title << (t2 - t1).count() << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  vector <unsigned> v(MAXN);
  unsigned s;
  timer t;

  srand(time(0));

  s = 0;
  for (unsigned q=0; q<MAXN; ++q) v[q] = rand();
  t.start();
  for (unsigned q=0, n=v.size(); q<n; ++q) s += v[q];
  t.stop();
  cout << s << endl;
  t.print("Index: ");

  s = 0;
  for (unsigned q=0; q<MAXN; ++q) v[q] = rand();
  t.start();
  for (auto x : v) s += x;
  t.stop();
  cout << s << endl;
  t.print("Byval: ");

  s = 0;
  for (unsigned q=0; q<MAXN; ++q) v[q] = rand();
  t.start();
  for (auto &x : v) s += x;
  t.stop();
  cout << s << endl;
  t.print("Byref: ");

  return 0;
}
```

Версия с виртуальными функциями: https://ideone.com/RCtNma

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int type;
  virtual int get() = 0;
  virtual ~base() {}
};

struct class1 : base
{
  class1() { type = 1; }
  virtual int get() { return 11; }
};

struct class2 : public base
{
  class2() { type = 2; }
  virtual int get() { return 27; }
};

class timer
{
  using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
  T t1, t2;
public:
  void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void stop() { t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void print() const { std::cout << "Time: " << (t2 - t1).count() << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  vector <base *> v;
  int s = 0;
  timer t;

  srand(time(0));
  for (unsigned q=0; q<50000000; ++q) v.push_back(rand()&1 ? (base*)new class1() : (base*)new class2());

  t.start();
  for (auto x : v) s += x->get();
  t.stop();

  cout << s << endl;
  t.print();

  for (auto x : v) delete x;

  return 0;
}
```

Версия со switch'ом по типу: https://ideone.com/tPlm81

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int type;
  virtual ~base() {}
};

struct class1 : base
{
  class1() { type = 1; }
  int get() { return 11; }
};

struct class2 : public base
{
  class2() { type = 2; }
  int get() { return 27; }
};

class timer
{
  using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
  T t1, t2;
public:
  void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void stop() { t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void print() const { std::cout << "Time: " << (t2 - t1).count() << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  vector <base *> v;
  int s = 0;
  timer t;

  srand(time(0));
  for (unsigned q=0; q<50000000; ++q) v.push_back(rand()&1 ? (base*)new class1() : (base*)new class2());

  t.start();
  for (auto x : v)
    switch (x->type)
    {
      case 1:   s += ((class1*)x)->get();   break;
      case 2:   s += ((class2*)x)->get();   break;
    }
  t.stop();

  cout << s << endl;
  t.print();

  for (auto x : v) delete x;

  return 0;
}
```

Версия со switch'ом по типу и циклом по индексу: https://ideone.com/4mnkSP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int type;
  virtual ~base() {}
};

struct class1 : base
{
  class1() { type = 1; }
  int get() { return 11; }
};

struct class2 : public base
{
  class2() { type = 2; }
  int get() { return 27; }
};

class timer
{
  using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
  T t1, t2;
public:
  void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void stop() { t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void print() const { std::cout << "Time: " << (t2 - t1).count() << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  vector <base *> v;
  int s = 0;
  timer t;

  srand(time(0));
  for (unsigned q=0; q<50000000; ++q) v.push_back(rand()&1 ? (base*)new class1() : (base*)new class2());

  t.start();
  for (unsigned q=0; q<v.size(); ++q)
    switch (v[q]->type)
    {
      case 1:   s += ((class1*)v[q])->get();   break;
      case 2:   s += ((class2*)v[q])->get();   break;
    }
  t.stop();

  cout << s << endl;
  t.print();

  for (auto x : v) delete x;

  return 0;
}
```

Версия со switch'ом по типу и циклом по индексу до переменной: https://ideone.com/3sIXHl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int type;
  virtual ~base() {}
};

struct class1 : base
{
  class1() { type = 1; }
  int get() { return 11; }
};

struct class2 : public base
{
  class2() { type = 2; }
  int get() { return 27; }
};

class timer
{
  using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
  T t1, t2;
public:
  void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void stop() { t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
  void print() const { std::cout << "Time: " << (t2 - t1).count() << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  vector <base *> v;
  int s = 0;
  timer t;

  srand(time(0));
  for (unsigned q=0; q<50000000; ++q) v.push_back(rand()&1 ? (base*)new class1() : (base*)new class2());

  t.start();
  for (unsigned q=0, n=v.size(); q<n; ++q)
    switch (v[q]->type)
    {
      case 1:   s += ((class1*)v[q])->get();   break;
      case 2:   s += ((class2*)v[q])->get();   break;
    }
  t.stop();

  cout << s << endl;
  t.print();

  for (auto x : v) delete x;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

удалось сделать минимально-работающий пример, показывающий данный эффект
в общем наверное ничего не сделать - данный пример работает примерно с той же скоростью, что и приведённый в первом посте.

обработка миллиона пакетов занимает 5000 мсек, хотя в принципе ничего не делается.

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual int
        add() const = 0;
};

class CBase : public IBase
{
protected:
    virtual int
        get() const = 0;

public:
    virtual int
        add() const override
    {
        return 0;
        return get();
    }
};

class CObject : public CBase
{
protected:
    int m_value;

    virtual int
        get() const override
    {
        return m_value;
    }

public:
    CObject(const int value) : m_value(value) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<IBase*> data;

    for (int index = 0; index < 1500; index++)
        data.push_back((IBase*)(new CObject(index)));


    const DWORD timer1 = ::GetTickCount();

    int count = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < 1000000; index++)
    {
        for (const auto &object : data)
            count += object->add();
    }

    const DWORD timer2 = ::GetTickCount();

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time: " << (timer2 - timer1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "press any key to exit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score -9):

Кто-то из великих сказал (наверное это был я) "программирование на с++ с использованием stl превращает с++ в яву со всеми вытекающими последствиями в смысле быстродействия". Все контейнеры stl годны только для мелких структур данных, которые не критичны по быстродействию. Когда начинаются терабайты, нужно писать свои контейнеры с учетом свойств своих данных и минимизировать обращения к куче.

UPD1:

Программирование на с++ с использованием stl получается даже хуже, чем ява, потому, что в яве есть сборщик мусора (в пределе сборщик мусора можно сделать даже с переупаковкой кучи) а в stl нет сборщика мусора и через некоторое время куча превращается в лоскутное одеяло.

UPD2:

> менял контейнер на обычный массив

Ничего быстрее обычного массива не бывает. Значит где-то в другом месте тормоза. А может это и есть максимум производительности.

> можно и от классов отказаться, шаблонов

Классы и шаблоны сами по себе не имеют накладных расходов по быстродействию. А вот stl имеет накладные расходы по быстродействию за счет частого обращения к куче. Причем от производителя к производителю и от версии к версии даже для одного производителя stl меняет свою внутреннюю реализацию, что делает непредсказуемым быстродействие stl-контейнеров.

UPD3:

> требуется определение метода по таблице виртуальных функций,

1. Далеко не все классы имеют таблицы виртуальных функций.
2. Если в задаче все-таки реально нужны классы с виртуальными функциями, то реализация виртуальных функций компилятором гораздо оптимальнее, чем реализация виртуальных функций "ручками".

UPD4:

> Есть вероятность, что switch или словарь отработает быстрее.

Неизвестно насколько оправдано применение производных классов в данном случае. Неизвестно даже есть ли там виртуальные функции. Но вряд-ли switch или еще что-то отработает быстрее, чем виртуальные функции. И это безотносительно к данной конкретной задаче.

Впрочем, это можно легко проверить. Написать простенькую иерархию классов и такую же функциональность реализовать самому. И замерить разность быстродействия. Думаю, что производители компиляторов делают такие тесты.

UPD5:

> Зачем stl более частое обращение к куче, чем обычному си масиву?

Затем, что без частого обращения к куче невозможно реализовать заявленный функционал контейнеров stl. Взять тот же vector. У него есть функция вставки в середину, в начало и в конец. Вместе с тем утверждается, что vector хранит данные непрерывно. То есть, чтобы вставить данные vector должен перекопировать все данные на новое место в куче, а это запрос нового места в куче, освобождение старых данных в куче и само копирование, которое тоже O(n).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95882/discussion-on-answer-by-pepsicoca1-c-----).