# скорость работы с динамическим массивом и std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, динамические-массивы

программировал умножение матрицы на вектор, и заметил что умножение с использованием простых динамических массивов выполняется в два раза быстрее в среднем чем с использованием std::vector, с чем это связано? ведь проверки на выход за пределы массив нет, вроде бы и оверхеда нет никакого почти значительного по сравнению с массивами, почему все-таки столь различное время работы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

//#include <omp.h>


void fillVector(std::vector<int>& vector)
{
  for (int i = 0;i < vector.size();++i) {
    vector[i] = rand() % 10;
  }
}

void fillMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix)
{
  for (int i = 0;i < matrix.size();++i) {
    for (int j = 0;j < matrix[i].size();++j) {
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
  }
}

void matmul(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix,
  const std::vector<int>& vector, std::vector<int>& result)
{
//#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0;i < matrix.size();++i) {
    result[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j) {
      result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
    }
  }
}

void fillVector(int* vector, const int n)
{
  for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
    vector[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
  }
}

void fillMatrix(int** matrix, const int n, const int m)
{
  for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
    for (int j = 0;j < m;++j) {
      matrix[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 10;
    }
  }
}

void matmul(int** matrix, int* vector, int* result, const int n, const int m)
{
//#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
    result[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int n = 15000;
  const int m = 15000;

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(m));
  std::vector<int> vector(m);
  std::vector<int> result(n);

  fillVector(vector);
  fillMatrix(matrix);

  clock_t startTime = clock();
  matmul(matrix, vector, result);
  clock_t endTime = clock();
  std::cout << endTime - startTime << "msec\n";

  int* vector1 = new int[m];
  int** matrix1 = new int* [n];
  for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
    matrix1[i] = new int[m];
  }
  int* result1 = new int[n];

  fillVector(vector1, m);
  fillMatrix(matrix1, n, m);

  startTime = clock();
  matmul(matrix1, vector1, result1, n, m);
  endTime = clock();
  std::cout << endTime - startTime << "msec\n";

  delete[] result1;
  delete[] vector1;
  for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
    delete[] matrix1[i];
  }
  delete[] matrix1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А тестили дебажную или релизную сброку? и каким компилятором?

Comment: @KoVadim релиз конечно x64, компилятор MSVC в vs19

Comment: для начала вынесите matrix.size()  из цикла. Оно хоть и константно, но не бесплатно.

Comment: @KoVadim хмм, да серьезно повлияло, но все же процентов на 15-20 вектор помедленней пока что

Comment: Ок, давайте уберем ещё один "затык". код `matrix[i][j]` для обычных массивов это просто пара умножений и сложений. В случае вектора там немножко больше. Плюс студия любит вставлять внутрь даже `[]` дополнительные проверки. я попробовал бы вынести `matrix[i]` за пределы цикла также.

Comment: @KoVadim, а можно пруф (ссылку или пример), что студия что-то вставляет? в реализации библиотеки там обычное `return (this->_Myfirst()[_Pos]);` в дебаг версии есть проверка отладочная)

Comment: Вы его сами и привели. В данном варианте есть как минимум одно разыменования (в 2019 студии код немного другой, но сути не меняет)

Comment: @KoVadim все помогло и время стало одинаковое, попробуйте раскомментировать директивы omp и подключить его в свойствах проекта, массив теперь опять быстрее становится

Comment: @KoVadim, разыменование это не проверки...

Comment: @Ildar omp интересная штука.подозреваю, что оно делает лишнее копирование вектора. Но тут мне сложно, я не специалист по omp

Comment: Вы хотите от красивого кода скорость, это мечты. Сначала используйте внутренние переменные в цикле : `int sum=0;..sum+= matrix[i][j] * vector[j];..result[i]=sum;` Так как чтение, запись в одно и тоже место это лишняя работа для доступа к памяти.

Answer (score 3):

Было похожее обсуждение:

[Перебор элементов контейнера - очень медленная операция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1000740/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Мой ответ там заминусовали, но тем не менее... :-)

Еще страшная история из прошлого:

[Грабли: gcc 4.8.1 не соответствует C++ 11](https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp/5333685.1)

Comment: боюсь, и тут заминусуют

Comment: @KoVadim, почему же?